# How can we start a node in warp sync mode?

Tags: parachain-collator, sync

Recently tried to run a collator node with --sync warp flags. The node exited with error "Warp sync enabled, but no warp sync provider configured". I was not able to find any more info on this. How can we configure a warp provider to run a parachain collator in warp mode?

Answer (score 1):

I think you might need these codes.

https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/441106ecbe2bc843adb248c8fab346af58ed9ffc/node/service/src/lib.rs#L908-L923d

But I think this can only be enabled for the relay chain. (if I'm wrong, please correct me)

Comment: Thanks for the help. Seems like newer substrate -node-template has warp mode configured as well but i am not sure if this can be configured on parachain.